# PowerShell script with specific date/time range

Tags: datetime, powershell, exchange-server

I am trying to run a powershell script for exchange 2010 to pull information from a specific date/time range.

**example:** show me amount of received emails from monday-friday time range 6am-11pm

```
get-messagetrackinglog -resultsize unlimited -Recipient TEST@TEST.COM -Server EXCHANGE -Start "3/4/2013 6:00:00 AM" -End "3/6/2013 23:00:00 PM" | select messageid -unique | measure
```

but I would like to make the date range not so static. so If i run the script at 11pm on Friday night, every week, how can i get it to do this query for the last 5 days.

I was trying adding in `(get-date).adddays(-5)` but I can't figure out how to add that in.

any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
for($i=-4,$i -lt 0,$i++){
    $start = (get-date -hour 6).adddays($i);
    $end = (get-date -hour 23).adddays($i);
    Write-host $start.DayoftheWeek  (get-messagetrackinglog -resultsize unlimited -Recipient TEST@TEST.COM -Server EXCHANGE -Start $start -End $end | select messageid -unique | measure).count 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The get-messagetrackinglog cmdlet only takes a single argument for -start and -end, so you can't specify that in a single command.

You can run 5 separate queries of the messagetracking logs from 6AM-11PM, each on different days and aggregate those results together, or you can do one query for all the logs from 6AM on the first day to 11PM on the last day, then filter out the ones that are timestamped between 11PM and 6AM in the interim days.

Answer (score 0):

Just trying to answer the part about the past date and hour and assuming you are running this at 11pm but want to go back to 6am (17hrs diff)...
Maybe use something like:

```
$past=(Get-Date).adddays(-5).addhours(-17)
```

And then try

```
-start $past -end (get-date)
```

Comment: You probably meant it the other way 'round: `-Start $past -End (Get-Date)`